# Formtastic nested form field not building has_one association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, formtastic

Given a User who can possibly be an Artist:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :artist
end
```

I've got a User & Artist nested form (using Formtastic gem):

```
<h1>Artist registration</h1>

<% @user.build_artist unless @user.artist %>

<%= semantic_form_for @user, :url => create_artist_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs :username %>

  <%= f.semantic_fields_for :artist do |a| %>
    <%= a.input :bio %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.buttons do %>
    <%= f.commit_button 'Register as Artist' %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is the :artist fields are not rendered.

I've also tried `f.inputs :for => :artist do |a|`.

For some reason, using `@user.build_artist` does not display the artist's fields in the form. If I try `@user.artist = Artist.new` I get an error, because it tries to save the Artist and validation fails.

How should I initialize the Artist model so I get the benefit of formtastic generators in a nested form? (Note that `@user` here is not a `:new_record?`)

Answer (score 3):

Did you remember to set `accepts_nested_attributes_for :artist` in user.rb?